# How to force NOEXPAND on a Common Expression Table (CTE)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

When I run the following query, the dbo.VerySlowTableValuedFunction() gets called many times. How can I modify it so that the slow function gets called only once.

```
with DatesT as (
    ....list of dates....
), slowT as 
(
     select *
     from dbo.VerySlowTableValuedFunction()
)
select DateS, (
     select top 1 [dataseries] 
     from [dataseries] 
     where DateS = p.DateS
     order by DateS desc
 ) as slowData
 from DatesT p
```

Comment: I guess one way would be to store slowT in a temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not way to do it as of SQL Server 2008.
This has been requested as a feature... but it's not clear it'll be included in Denali.